# Did 150,000 people march against Muslim Immigration in Poland?

Tags: islam, social-media, poland

The following video was posted on the Facebook page of [Milo Yiannopoulos](https://www.facebook.com/myiannopoulos/videos/879908358813727/).

The video has the following text:

> 150,000 MARCHED AGAINST MUSLIM IMMIGRATION IN POLAND
>
> BUT THE MAINSTREAM MEDIA DID NOT COVER IT

So is it true that 150,000 people in Poland marched against Muslim immigration and the MSM didn't cover it?

Comment: Does the video give a date for when this occurred? A location? Does it cite non-mainstream media which did report a march for such a purpose and with such a turnout? Without these details, it might not be falsifiable.

Answer (score 12):

As is often the case, [Snopes has already looked at this](http://www.snopes.com/poland-march-refugees/).

**A large march in Poland did take place on 11th November 2015, but it was well reported in mainstream media.** Numbers were less than 150,000 and not all were protesting Muslim immigration.

Reports on the attendance at the march vary, with organizers claiming 50,000, and police 25,000.

The march was widely reported:

> Social media claims about the marches in Poland further held that the events were ignored or purposely covered up by Europe’s mainstream media. That was easily proved false, as Britain’s Telegraph (“EU flag burned as tens of thousands join Warsaw nationalist demo”), Russia’s RT (“‘Communists will be hanging’: Nationalist march commemorates Poland’s Independence Day”), Financial Times (“Polish nationalists rail against Brussels in show of strength”), Radio Poland (“Poland commemorates Independence Day”), Bloomberg (“Thousands March on Independence Day as Police Converge on Warsaw”), Britain’s Express (“EU flag burned as thousands join nationalist march in Poland”), and U.S. News & World Report (“Polish extreme nationalists hold large anti-migrant march on Independence Day”) all covered the rally on or around 11 November 2015.

The Snopes article gives links to the media reports.

The march was in celebration of Polish independence. While there was a distinct anti-EU theme to the march, not all were protesting Muslim immigration specifically.

Comment: This leaves out the bit where one group builds a rainbow and then the other group burn it down https://assets.vice.com/content-images/contentimage/122233/13.jpg

Comment: @daniel, would adding the part about the rainbow have improved the answer in any meaningful way?

Comment: @ABailey it's probably worth noting that the mob is probably not fond of the gays, as well as probably not being fond of immigration and Islam.  It's all speculation as from the video we can just see that they like the polish flag, and the crowned white eagle, and that's alright cause both of these things are awesome.

Comment: @daniel, The rainbow is called the "tęcza".  It's in Warsaw.  On 11 November 2013, it was set ablaze after a different protest turned into a riot.  As this incident took place in 2013 and this answer references a march from 2015, it's safe to say that the rainbow burn has nothing to do with this question.